# rails select view from parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, handler, ab-testing

I'm trying to have some architecture in place for testing some hidden features (i.e. ab testing without the user interaction).

I though about using a parameter to select a specific view if it exists but fall back to the original otherwise.

This probably will work best if it also affects partials.

The idea is to route something like:

```
.../mycontroller/myview?hf=extra
```

to `views/mycontroller/myview.hf_extra.html.erb` if exists, otherwise `views/mycontroller/myview.html.erb`.

The same for all partials too.

This looks like defining an extra template handler,right? 
Does this make sense or should I attempt some different?

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of different ways to accomplish this. If it's an entirely different layout/thing maybe something along the lines of this (from the rails guilds)

```
def show
  @book = Book.find(params[:id])
  if @book.special?
    render action: "special_show" and return
  end
  render action: "regular_show"
end
```

Comment: Yes, but he idea would be to not code this in every single method from every controller, but in a more general manner. Just like erb or html handlers are not coded in every method

Comment: you may want to update your question to reflect that